# turkish character instead html

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, turkish

I have a problem: when I typed for html data

```
Uri url = new Uri(urlAddress);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9");
html = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Data is coming, OK. But when i transfer to StringBuilder to incoming data StringBuilder seems for example 'Ş' looks like 'Å', 'Ü' looks like 'Ã', 'ü' looks like 'Ã¼', etc...

Notes I tryed:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=ISO-8859-9' />");
sb.Append("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9' />";
```

Also I tryed ISO-8859-9, window1254, utf8.

Do you have that can help me?

EDIT:
I solved the problem. Thank you.
Problem's solution is:

```
Uri url = new Uri(urlAddress);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadData(url);
var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Maybe would need to someone.

Comment: This is for C#, ASP.NET

Comment: Thank you Selman22 for edited to entry.